# The field post.Post.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'draft1.myuser', but app 'draft1' doesn't provide model 'myuser'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to change my user model and getting this error on all my instances where I refer to `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` in my model fields:

```
ValueError: The field account.EmailAddress.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'draft1.myuser', but app 'draft1' doesn't provide model 'myuser'.
The field admin.LogEntry.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'draft1.myuser', but app 'draft1' doesn't provide model 'myuser'.
The field comment.Comment.has_downvoted was declared with a lazy reference to 'draft1.myuser', but app 'draft1' doesn't provide model 'myuser'.
The field comment.Comment.has_upvoted was declared with a lazy reference to 'draft1.myuser', but app 'draft1' doesn't provide model 'myuser'.
The field comment.Comment.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'draft1.myuser', but app 'draft1' doesn't provide model 'myuser'.
The field comment.CommentScore.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'draft1.myuser', but app 'draft1' doesn't provide model 'myuser'.
...
```

Here's the relevent code:

**draft1/models.py**

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'),max_length=30 , unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'first_name'
```

**settings.py**

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'draft1.MyUser'
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: You should show the EmailAddress model.

Comment: I haven't made one so that must be django allauth: http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html

Comment: Have you made an initial migration for `draft1`'s models?

Comment: Yeah I did. I've deleted the model so this isn't a problem for myself anymore. Still unsure about the error though.